# How can i find item in wpf listbox having grouped list bind to it?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My listbox is having a grouped list so basically I want to find listbox group item index with item value. Listbox is having item source bind to it and is having `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` set from code behind.

What I have tried yet are as follow:-

```
int index = istboxName.Items.IndexOf(ListBindToItemSource.particularParameterValue);
```

Give index=-1 always.

Another solution I tried is:

```
int index = ListboxName.Items.Groups.IndexOf(ListBindToItemSource.particularParameterValue);
```

Same result index=-1 always.

Comment: Did you try int index = istboxName.Items.IndexOf(listboxName.SelectedItem); or int index = istboxName.SelectedIndex; ??

Comment: @ViVi Actually I don't want to get the index of SelectedItem, what I want is to find index  of listbox item by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never need to access the items that way, instead access the item in your bound source and manipulate that. If you want to change anything in the view, like e.g. a `Background`, bind it on your item and change it at the source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply H.B. As I am new to wpf a sample code would be more explanatory, if you could provide.

Comment: That wouldn't help much without knowing what you try to do, the core is fairly straightforward: It's just calling `IndexOf` on your source list. Your question should not be how to find the item but rather what you are trying to do in the abstract, like "deleting the selected item" or whatever. People would be able to answer that much better.

Comment: Actually i want to find an element in listbox and change its background colour or simply highlight that element in listbox, without changing the selectedItem of listbox.

Comment: Then bind the `Background` in the `ItemContainerStyle` to a property on your item, then get the item from the source list and change said property, simple.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this and will let you know.